# How to reduce ghost flow from boiler to indirect water tank

Tags: hvac, water-heater, boiler

I recently had an indirect-water tank added to my multizone gas-powered hydronic heating system.  The supply line from the boiler to the water tank heats up considerably every time one of my heating zones is enabled, even when the circulator for the water heater is off. This seems wasteful. I also worry it will cause irregular (and perhaps dangerous) domestic hot-water temperatures, since heat is reaching the water tank in an uncontrolled manner.

Questions:

1. Is there a simple piping fix (e.g. heat trap?) that will prevent boiler water from reaching the water tank unless its circulator pump is enabled?
2. Is this evidence of an installation/design error, or is this a common drawback of indirect water tanks?

Edit: this diagram, *with* zone circulators but *without*  zone valves, matches my install: [image]

Comment: Had that problem once, a bit backwards from your design.  A solenoid shut off valve wired into the pump should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

When we design a heating system we give domestic hot water (DHW) priority, we allow a heatinhg circuit via gravity to flow through the DHW tank, it's logical that DHW should be heated to set temperature as long as heat is created, by gas or any means, the heat allowed in the tank is controled via a cylinder thermostat and DHW zone valve.

Your questions:

1. The transfere is on purpose, the idea being supply DHW flow on any demand, but will stop when tank reaches set
   temerature.
2. Answered in answer 1

Comment: Good to know this is by design.  Is the zone valve built into the tank? Is it powered?  I ask because I don't see it, or how it is powered. In my system, I only see a circulator pump, controlled by a thermostat, that actively _pumps_ water through the tank.  The pump, however, doesn't do anything to stop _passive_ flow from gravity.  So I don't fully see how the temperature is regulated unless the valve you mention is somehow integrated into the tank.

Comment: The zone valve will be on the pipework before it enters the tanks heating  flow circuit, if you edit your post and show a picture of your tank I can label the equipment. Sorry did not see your edit, it's the system zone valves

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, I do not have zone valves, only circulator pumps.  Hence, my concern that boiler water is heating the water tank in an uncontrolled manner.